# Visualization of density gradients in a fluid

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, color

I want to visualize periodic changes in the density of a gel-like fluid due to external forces. The fluid is contained in a hollow cylinder in which I have modeled a "cutaway" section.

I would have imagined to just visualize the fluid as a 2D surface which is darker in some areas and lighter in other. Two different states should probably be sufficient, as long as I manage to get a nice transition between these two states.

Does any of you have an idea how I could do so?

Best regards!

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve. Would an animated texture be enough? Maybe you could [upload your blend file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), so that someone can have a closer look at it. I don't understand the part about the cutaway section.

Comment: Could you upload some reference image?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any reference image but I can try to sketch a basil mock up the next time I'm at work.      Summarized: I have a contained fluid where laser beams are passing through. The fluid changes its density in a specific periodical manner on specific spatial points inside of the container. This causes the laser beams to get deflected which results e.g. in an focus point that oszillates up and down in the laser beam.

Comment: And this density change is what I want to somehow display in the animation. I was thinking about maybe show it due to changing color intensity inside of the cutaway section of the optical element with the fluid.

Comment: apparentrly i am not able to upload image, since imgur rejects whatever i try to upload. It is really just a cylinder cut top to bottom down the middle.